# How to identify which table the values belong to from a view?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following unionized view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CombinedData]
AS 
   (SELECT * FROM [Data1] 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [Data2]
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [Data3]);
```

As well as this `Rejects` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rejects] 
(
    [Dimension - PK] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Reject] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Currently, I use the following stored procedure to check for any rejects (data missing in primary key column in other dimension tables (i.e. `Org`) that is showing in `CombinedData` view "Foreign Key" related columns) and insert any results into the `Rejects` table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] ([Dimension - PK], [Reject])
    SELECT DISTINCT 'Org - Org Code' AS [Dimension - PK], [Org Code] AS [Reject]
    FROM [CombinedData]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [Org]
                      WHERE [Org].[Org Code] = [CombinedData].[Org Code]);
```

So if there are rejects, I end up with an output like this in the `Rejects` table:

```
Dimension - PK    Reject
Org - Org Code    A12356
Org - Org Code    90-45F
Org - Org Code    123456
```

How do I identify where the reject is coming from exactly from the unionized view? i.e. I'd like something like this:

```
Source Table Dimension - PK    Reject
--------------------------------------
Data2        Org - Org Code    A12356
Data3        Org - Org Code    90-45F
Data3        Org - Org Code    123456
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between UNION and UNION ALL? Any particular row in your resultset (using your current query) might actually exist in all three tables (or even multiple times within one table). Be careful what you assume.

Comment: @SMor what i know is that UNION returns a result set without duplicates...i see what youre saying, that there may be a duplicate between multiple tables which may get ignored..hmm, but the problem is that this data is fed into an SSAS tabular cube, which the users see data through. I dont want them to see duplicates if i change it to UNION ALL :/ although i dont think there may be duplicates anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the source table at the point of union:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CombinedData] AS
    -- Be sure you really need 'union' as opposed to 'union all'
    SELECT 'Data1' as SourceTable, * FROM [Data1] 
    UNION
    SELECT 'Data2' as SourceTable, * FROM [Data2]
    UNION
    SELECT 'Data3' as SourceTable, * FROM [Data3];
```

Then just use it:

```
-- I think you may want 'not null' as opposed to 'null'.
-- But I'll leave that to you.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rejects] (
    SourceTable sysname not null,
    [Dimension - PK] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Reject] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

---- 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] (SourceTable, [Dimension - PK], [Reject])
SELECT 
DISTINCT   SourceTable,
           'Org - Org Code' AS [Dimension - PK], 
           [Org Code] AS [Reject]
FROM       [CombinedData]
WHERE      NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
               FROM [Org]
               WHERE [Org].[Org Code] = [CombinedData].[Org Code]
           );
```

Comment: Excellent answer, its exactly what i need, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you need to Identify your `Source Table` in view, so you can add a column in all of your select and identify your `Source Table` name. I think this may help :

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CombinedData]
  AS (
    SELECT 'Data1' [Source Table], * FROM [Data1] 
    UNION
    SELECT 'Data2' [Source Table], * FROM [Data2]
    UNION
    SELECT 'Data3' [Source Table], * FROM [Data3]
  );
```